# How to change color bar to be non linear, whilst data is displayed normally?

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I would like to achieve similar results to this:

```
Data=magic(100);
c=[1 10/3 10 100/3 100 1000/3 1000 10000/3 10000];
contourf(log(Data(:,:)),log(c));
colormap(bone);  %Color palate named "bone"
caxis(log([c(1) c(length(c))]));
colorbar('FontSize',11,'YTick',log(c),'YTickLabel',c);
```

With the results here:

[image: results]

Except, I want to instead plot `pcolor(x,y,z)`, where `x`, `y`, `z` are 3 matrices of *1000*-by-*90*. I want the data in `x`, `y`, `z` to not be logarithmic, instead I want values that are not seen well to be easier to see. See image below for example of data:

[image: data to change colormap / colorbar]

I would like to see more the variability above the yellow layer at the bottom between `13`-`16`.

So I tried the code for MATLAB 2012b (I managed to get it remotely) and tried the code below given by the first answer:

```
figure;
ax1=subplot(2,1,2)
hp = pcolor(x,y,z);
shading flat
cdat = get(hp,'cdata');
hc = colorbar;
set(hc,'yscale','log','ytick',logspace(log10(min(cdat(:))),log10(max(cdat(:))),11));
```

But I obtained the same plot with different colorbar tick marks...

[image: results of this here..]

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `yscale` property of the colorbar from `'linear'` to `'log'`. You'll have to adjust the tick positions manually.

HG1 version, i.e. for older versions of MATLAB:

```
n = 10;
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:n);
z = 1000*rand(n);

figure;
hp = pcolor(x,y,z);
cdat = get(hp,'cdata');
hc = colorbar;
set(hc,'yscale','log','ytick',logspace(log10(min(cdat(:))),log10(max(cdat(:))),11));
```

You'd still need to set the colorbar tick positions to prettier, manual values:

[image: result]

Unfortunately, I couldn't get a HG2-compliant solution to work. The problem is that while `hc.Ticks` is still present, I can't find a reference [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar-properties.html?searchHighlight=colorbar) to any properties relating to the linear/logarithmic scale of the colorbar. I'll update if I find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, however I receive the following message: `Error using matlab.graphics.illustration.ColorBar/set
There is no yscale property on the ColorBar class.`. I tried something similar to this method a few days ago and also had the same message, may be related to my version of Matlab (R2014b)?

Comment: Ooops, HG2:) Sorry @Michael (and dasdingonesin), I have R2012b. I'll read into it in a sec.

Comment: @Michael any chance that `hc.YScale='log'; hc.YTick=...` works?:)

Comment: hc.Yscale
`No appropriate method, property, or field Yscale for class matlab.graphics.illustration.ColorBar.`

Comment: @Michael capital 'S'. It should work, I'll update my post in a second.

Comment: sorry, @Andras Deak, hc.YScale = 'log';
`No public field YScale exists for class matlab.graphics.illustration.ColorBar.`

Comment: @Michael I can't find the corresponding property in the documentation. I'll try to figure out how to do this, but I'll need more time. Please stand by, and hope for someone with HG2 experience to help in the mean time;)

Comment: thanks for your help so far. I tried the code you provided for Matlab 2012b and it didn't work either for some reason.

Comment: @Michael thanks for the feedback, that is odd. Seems to work for me in 2012b. What exactly do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: I was referring to when using my data, it was fine copy and pasting your example above. For my data, the colorbar ticklabels were similar to what is shown in your example (few decimal places) but it wasn't logarithmic. The colormap didn't change at all.

Comment: so for example, it only changed the ticklabels from 13,14,15 etc.. to 13.2332 14.2462 15.4967

Comment: @Michael the colorbar colors shouldn't change, see your example images. The ticks, however, should indicate logarithmic steps. For instance, check where the half maximum is located. On a linear scale, they should be in the middle. On a logarithmic one, they are located near the top. So are you sure it's not logarithmic?

Comment: I added an image to my original post with the results. Yes sorry I was referring mainly to the tick labels. The labels don't seem to be logarithmic.

Comment: @Michael take a very close look at your yticks:) Top one is 23.3, bottom one is 12.4. This means the median is above 17.8. This value seems to be above the middle of the colorbar, indicating that the scale is not linear. Your problem is that your data is on a single order of magnitude, and not spread over several orders of magnitude. In this case there's hardly a difference between a logarithmic and a linear scale.